# nodeschool stream-adventure #6 concat

Tags: node.js

I am leaning node.js from the begining. 
There is the question #6 in the stream-adventure@nodeschool,

> You will be given text on process.stdin. Buffer the text and reverse it using
>   the `concat-stream` module before writing it to stdout.

and it's my answer:

```
var concatStream = require('concat-stream');
var through2 = require('through2');
var split = require('split');
var inv = through2(trans, flush);
process.stdin
  .pipe(process.stdout)
  .pipe(concatStream(inv));

function trans (buffer, enc, callback){
  var tr = buffer.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
  this.push(tr);
  callback();
}

function flush (callback){
  callback();
}
```

I has already check the solution,
but i just want to try the module "through2".

It can't work (seems like the endless loop),
can anyone help this one?
Thank a lot!

Comment: have you tried getting rid of this.push(tr) and just pass "tr" to your callback?

Comment: I try to kick this.push(tr) out, and then use callback() = tr. but it's still not work... Also i try only tr or callback(tr), all can not done.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is this one:

```js
const concat = require('concat-stream');
const through = require('through2');
const stream = require('stream');

function allRead(buf){
        const reversed = buf.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
        const streamReversed = stream.Readable.from(reversed); // or console.log(reversed)
        streamReversed.pipe(process.stdout);
}
process.stdin.pipe(concat(allRead));
```

you only need to pipe the stdin stream to concat and wait all data to be collected. In the end reverse the all buffers ( converted to string ) and send it to stdout ( with console log or with new stream ).